# How to perform Image RGB Normalization in Android OpenCV?

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to perform image normalization, using OpenCV 2.4.8 for Android. My test device is a samsung S3.

I have written a JNI function as shown below to perform Image Normalization.

My definition of Image Normalization is as follows :

```
r' is 255* r/(r+g+b)
g' is 255* g/(r+g+b)
b' is 255* b/(r+g+b)
```

Now I need to implement this. And I have written a function to perform this. This doesnt seem to work. I am confident of my other portions of my App (i.e. they are bug free). Only this part causes a problem.

I may have not written this function properly. Pls help.

I have also attached a screenshot of my result. If you look at this image, only half portion looks normalized (but its actually not normalized, it just looks that way) & the other half is not. To fix this, I tried changing the rows with cols in the for-loop, and the result was the same.

[image]

The code for this is also presented.

Looking forward to some help. (FYI - I am totally new to openCV). Thanks for understanding.

```
void NormalizeRGB(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong img)
{
    Mat& imgM  = *(Mat*)img;
    vector<Mat> rgb;
    int cols = imgM.cols;
    int rows = imgM.rows;
    for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<cols; j++)
        {
            Vec3b bgrPixel = imgM.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
            float total = bgrPixel.val[0] + bgrPixel.val[1] + bgrPixel.val[2] + 0.00001;
            bgrPixel.val[0] = (uchar) 255*bgrPixel.val[0]/total;
            bgrPixel.val[1] = (uchar) 255*bgrPixel.val[1]/total;
            bgrPixel.val[2] = (uchar) 255*bgrPixel.val[2]/total;
            imgM.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = bgrPixel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried changing the type frmo uchar to float. I can see some jitter effect, but this makes the crash after about 5seconds.

Comment: Maybe you are getting values larger than 255? You should reset the value to 255 if it is larger than 255. And when I say 255 i mean whatever float value is representing 255.

Comment: I cannot get values more than 255. Because, the ratio bgrPixel.val[]/total will be less than or equal to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problems.

I was trying to use this function to read an RGBA Matrix image. A RGBA Matrix image is of type Vec4.

I was trying to read it as a Vec3 ~ this used to cause the above problem.

With this small change, I was able to get my expected results.