# How to normalize an image to a range of values

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, javacv

In a publication, I read that an image should be normalized from [0 to M].
I searched google for a normalization method and I get [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528925/how-to-perform-image-rgb-normalization-in-android-opencv), which is the closest to my needs. But still I do not know how to normalize an image to a range of values?

Please let me know how to normalize an image to a range of values and is there any opencv method that does that normalization operation?

**Update**:

concerning the norm_type, i found a comparisons between L1 and L2 [here](http://www.chioka.in/differences-between-the-l1-norm-and-the-l2-norm-least-absolute-deviations-and-least-squares/).should i just pick any one of them or there is a specific norm_Type suitable for image normalization

Comment: usually L2 norm is used.

Comment: @berak but as my input image is grayscale, when i normalize it from 0-100 with L2 or L1, the resultant image is black. but when i use the same range with normalization type minMax, the resultant image is not black and it's contents are visible

Answer (score 3):

What you want is [`cv::normalize`.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize)  Also, its Java equivalent can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#normalize(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)).

Comment: or rather it's [java equivalent](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#normalize(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat))

Comment: Ah thanks, I always struggle to find that, I have bookmarked it for future reference.

Comment: @berak concerning the norm_type, i found a comparisons between L1 and L2 here:http://www.chioka.in/differences-between-the-l1-norm-and-the-l2-norm-least-absolute-deviations-and-least-squares/  .should i just pick any one of them or there is a specific norm_Type suitable for image normalization

Comment: @user2121 the norm function is overloaded. you want this one `void normalize(Mat src,
             Mat dst,
             double alpha,
             double beta,
             int norm_type)` if im reading it correctly this scales (and possibly shifts) the values so for you `alpha=0` and `beta=M`